# How to get the currently selected locale in IE browser using javascript or Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, angular-translate

var x = window.navigator.userLanguage;

var y=window.navigator.language;

var browserCulture = this.clientInformation.browserLanguage;

I tried  this on chrome and firefox these browsers giving the currently selected locale exactly like(ja ,fr). But IE always giving en-US only as selected locale. Is there anyway to get the currently selected browser locale in IE.

Comment: There's nothing to guarantee the user has ever gone through the browser settings to change the locale. I actually believe most of them wouldn't.

Comment: @MuthukannanKanniappan you mentioned  this.clientInformation.browserLanguage; to use but this also gives same result as en-US